# R.java is not created automatically in android

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I'm using eclipse to make my project but whenever Im making a new project, R.java is not getting created as this file creates automatically i did all things doing>clean>build automatically,android tools>add compatibility libraries and in android SDK manager build android tools option is not there even i tried installing android tool every time it stuck in b/w please help me out.

Comment: chk after restarting the eclipse

Comment: R.java will not be generated if there is an error in your code or resource files. Maybe this could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem through a good two or three reinstalls of the entire SDK. What I found was I had multiple versions of the Java JRE on my machine and they were interfering with each other. I removed them all and reinstalled the latest JRE and everything was good to go with the SDK, no longer receiving this R.java problem. Something to check.